# Force execution of GCMNetworkManager OneoffTask in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using GcmNetworkManager to schedule a OneoffTask with an execution windows starting from 0. In the [documentations](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/OneoffTask) it mentions

> Note that you can request a one-off task to be executed at any point in the future, but to prevent abuse the scheduler will only set an alarm at a minimum of 30 seconds in the future. Your task can still be run earlier than this if some network event occurs to wake up the scheduler.

This this is problematic for me since I have to wait 30 seconds for a task to be executed whereas I want it to be executed immediately if possible. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to be able to force execution in order to debug your OneoffTask?

Currently you cannot trigger a previously scheduled task. There is however an adb shell command that you can run to trigger a special oneoff debug task with a specific tag. The [documentation on GcmNetworkManager](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager) has the specifics.

Or do you mean that you want your OneoffTask to be able to run immediately?

Unfortunately this is not possible without some event *other than an alarm* taking place to wake-up the network manager. The way the GNM currently works is that a client calling schedule(Task) is considered a wake-up (or any of the other API calls for that matter).

If you scheduled your task and then scheduled another one shortly after the second "schedule" call would likely bump the GNM into running the first. This is undocumented and not part of the API and will likely change so I don't recommend using it to do anything other than for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to achieve force immediate execution of any task.

Though the approach below might seem to be bad code at first glance but after writing code for background data sync using GcmNetworkManager, most of developers would like to reuse same piece of code when app is in foreground. Why should any app have one GcmTskService and one AsyncTask/IntentService, both calling the same data sync API endpoint?

I faced the same problem and achieved the immediate execution of one-off-task using below code snippet-

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent != null && MY_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand - called by our code);
        if (network-is-connected)) {
            // do below calls in run method of a thread
                TaskParams taskParams = new TaskParams(TASK_TAG);
                int result = onRunTask(taskParams);
                if (result == GcmNetworkManager.RESULT_RESCHEDULE) {
                // schedule task
                }
                stopSelf();
            // thread's run end
        } else {
            // schedule task
            stopSelf();
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    } else {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand - called by GCM Nw Mngr");
        // call super so that GCM's code may run as it was intended
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```